# windows_package install types

Tags: chef-infra, silent-installer, textpad

I am trying to use Chef to install a few programs for development purposes such as Visual Code, TextPad and a handful of others.

I am having a problem determining the installer type and options to make it install silently.  For example, I can use the /VERYSILENT option with Visual Code and it will install unattended, but then it will start the editor.  Another example is TextPad using InstallShield, but it seems to be wrapped in a Windows msiexec executable that doesn't pass the installer commands along...

In general, this seems incredibly painful and I am wondering:

1: has someone built a resource to install these specific packages?
2: am I making this more difficult than it should be?  It's seeming VERY obscure and unpredictable.  direction/insight are very much appreciated.